# The member with identity 'FaseProjeto_Fase_Target' does not exist in the metadata collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Estou com um erro muito estranho... não faço a minima do que seja.

Esta é minha classe:

```
 public class FaseProjeto
{
    public int IdProjeto { get; set; }
    public int IdFase { get; set; }
    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public virtual FaseModelo Fase { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
    public StatusProjetoFase Situacao { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

}
```

Esse é o mapeamento dela:

```
public FaseProjetoMap()
    {

        // Define nome da Tabela
        ToTable("FaseProjeto");

        // Chave primária composta
        HasKey(po => new { po.IdProjeto, po.IdFase });

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.IdProjeto)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.IdFase)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.IdProjeto).HasColumnName("Projeto_Id");
        Property(t => t.IdFase).HasColumnName("Fase_Id");


        HasRequired(fp => fp.Projeto)
            .WithMany(p => p.Fases)
            .HasForeignKey(f=>f.IdProjeto);

        HasRequired(fp => fp.Fase)
            .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(f=>f.IdFase);

    }
```

Aí eu tenho essa classe que herda de fase projeto:

```
 public class FaseProjetoPlanejamento : FaseProjeto
{

    public virtual OrgaoPublico Orgao { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjetoLicitacao Objeto { get; set; }

    public virtual LocalizacaoObra Localizacao { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Documento> Documentos 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Projeto.GetDocumentos();
        }
    }

    public virtual NCode.Orcamento.Model.Ent.Orcamento Orcamento 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Projeto.GetOrcamento();
        }
    }

    public override FaseModelo Fase
    {
        get { return ModeloProjetoObraSetorPublico.FasePlanejamento; }
        set { }
    }


}
```

Quando eu vou salvar essa classe com EF me retorna o seguinte erro:

> The member with identity 'FaseProjeto_Fase_Target' does not exist in
>   the metadata collection. Nome do parâmetro: identity

Answer (score 0):

Poderia debugar e falar qual linha exatamente da o erro rs, acredito que algo está com o nome incorreto no seu mapeamento ou não está preenchendo corretamente a entidade, verifique novamente nesta parte do seu código:

```
    HasRequired(fp => fp.Projeto)
        .WithMany(p => p.Fases)
        .HasForeignKey(f=>f.IdProjeto);

    HasRequired(fp => fp.Fase)
        .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f=>f.IdFase);
```